# The Layout page doesn't load css (asp.net mvc)

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use the following bundle to load css and it works :

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/jqGrid-styles").Include(
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css",
                "~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css"));
```

...

In my layout page this works :

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/jqGrid-styles")
```

And if i try simply adding the links to page it doesn't work .

This doesn't work at all:

```
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**Can someone explain my why by simply adding the links to the page this doesn't work ?** The files are there in the correct location.

Comment: Can you add the HTML produced from the <link> elements, and tell if these stylesheets are requested from the server, and what's the result?

Comment: i think dot in file names may create problem instead of `.` use `-`

Comment: the html is : <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" ></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css"  ></link>

Comment: the page inspector says its never used

Comment: @Kartikeya dots shouldn't be a problem

Comment: i think it may be a caching problem. i deleted all the cache but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [Url.Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.118).aspx) method:-

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css") rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css") rel="stylesheet" />
```

You need to pick the files from applications `absolute` path.

Comment: you are wrong. MVC is part of ASP.NET, and can definitely interpret URLs like in the question and replace the tilde with the base URL. We do it ourselves with no problems. And you need to add an opening quote mark inside your Url.Content call.

Comment: @TsahiAsher - Thanks for pointing, Corrected! Also, as pointed by OP the resulting href is `href="/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"` which in my view is wrong.

Comment: What's wrong with it? If his site is in the root of the domain, it's perfectly OK.

Comment: it is adviced to use `@Url.Content()` helper while working in mvc but i don't think this will solve OP's problem...

Comment: @TsahiAsher - Its working for you because probably you are running your app locally, check this probelm with ASP.NET `MVC` well explained here:-http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/04/22/test-you-asp-net-mvc-or-webforms-application-on-iis-7-in-30-seconds.aspx

Comment: I'm running on a local IIS, not Casini. My root is localhost/MyWebSite/ and MVC replaces the tilde with `/MyWebSite/` with no problems.

Comment: @TsahiAsher - Okay host it in IIS without making any changes and check.

Comment: We are. We have production code on an intranet site, doing just that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, it is basic html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" ></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" ></link>
```